# OleDbException while trying to read excel file in c# - External table is not in the expected format

Tags: c#, excel, connection-string, oledb

I'm developing an MVC .Net web application, and I want to read some data from Excel file.
I am using those connection strings:

```
if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
{
    excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\"" +
    fileLocation + "\";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"";
}
else if (fileExtension == ".xls")
{
    excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
    fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"";
}
```

Reading .xls files works great, but trying to read .xlsx files (created in Excel 2013) is not working, giving me the exception:

#### External table is not in the expected format.

I've been trying all the possible connection strings that I found:

```
excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\"" +
fileLocation + "\";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"";

excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\"" +
fileLocation + "\";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=2\"";

excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\"" +
fileLocation + "\";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=2\"";

...
...
...
```

but the I can't solve this problem.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hey your connection is looks good.like this

```
public static string path = @"C:\src\RedirectApplication\RedirectApplication\301s.xlsx";
public static string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
```

But make sure Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable package is installed on your machine.You can download from here [Link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

For excel connection string you can navigate this url [Link](http://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/)

Comment: no.... i installed it but it didn't help (what Microsoft Access ha to do with it?)

Comment: Can you show me your `fileLocation` variable contents

Comment: i also tried the @... the fileLocation content is: "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\Book1.xlsx" and the whole connection string is: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\Book1.xlsx";Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"